# What are the 5 cords of sensual pleasures?

Tags: jhana, six-senses

I looked it up but the person answer was unclear. I read greed which is a sense desire of unprofitable things (Which if I'm correct is different from sense desire of objects) has all 5. So doesn't that mean when suppressing the defilement i should suppress all 5 cords separately kind of like you do the hindrances.

Comment: If you're asking about something you read, can you add a reference or link to what you read?

Comment: Bonn answerd it. I just wanted to know the 5 cord of sense pleasures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The five *kāmaguṇa* are:

1. color
2. sound
3. smell
4. flavor
5. phoṭṭhabba (=temperature, matter, and *vayo*).

They tie the kāma-person to live in kāma-bhava.

*kāma* means "living in *kāma loka*"; and *guṇa* means "a binder".

So, the five kāmaguṇa are things that kāma-taṇha (addicting to drug), and bhava-taṇha (addicting to becoming, born to be, future birth).

See the first part of the [mahadukkhakkhandhasutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.013.than.html) for more information:

> Now what, monks, is the allure of sensuality? These **five strings of sensuality**. Which five? **Forms cognizable via the eye** — agreeable, pleasing, charming, endearing, fostering desire, enticing. **Sounds cognizable via the ear**... **Aromas cognizable via the nose**... **Flavors cognizable via the tongue**... **Tactile sensations cognizable via the body** — agreeable, pleasing, charming, endearing, fostering desire, enticing. Now whatever pleasure or joy arises in dependence on these five strands of sensuality, that is the allure of sensuality.

Answer (score 0):

*guṇa* also has two other meanings, besides string.  One is "quality" and another is "to multiply".  Most translators choose the "strings that bind" meaning, but it's been noted that these other two meanings also aren't unreasonable in this context - namely "proliferation resulting from the senses" (from the *multiply* meaning) and simply "the five sensual qualities".